# How to make a specific type belong to a family of types?

Tags: .net, f#

I'm trying to make a collection that holds multiple possible types. This is an example of how I'd want it to look:

```
type Position = Vector2
type Velocity = Vector2
type Appearance = String

type Component = Position | Velocity | Appearance

let components = List<Dictionary<string, Component>>()
let pos = Dictionary<string, Position>()

components.Add(pos) // Type "Position" does not match with type "Component"
```

I want to declare specific types that still fit under a general type. Is there a way that I can write my code like this? Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Do you understand that Component.Position and Position are not one and the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are are a couple of things you have in your code here:

**Type Abbreviations** ([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/type-abbreviations-%5Bfsharp%5D))

```
type Position = Vector2
type Velocity = Vector2
type Appearance = String
```

Type abbreviations just define another name for an existing type, the type on the left and right and precisely equivalent and can be used interchangeably.

To give an example pertinent to this question, in F# there is a type abbreviation for the standard .NET `List`, it's called [`ResizeArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.resizearray%5B't%5D-type-abbreviation-%5Bfsharp%5D).  It's defined like this:

```
type ResizeArray<'T> = System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>
```

It saves you having to open `System.Collections.Generic` in order to use it and it helps to avoids confusion with the [`list`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.list%5B't%5D-type-abbreviation-%5Bfsharp%5D) type in F# but it doesn't do anything other than add a new name for an existing type.

**Disciminated Unions** ([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/discriminated-unions-%5Bfsharp%5D))

```
type Component = Position | Velocity | Appearance
```

Here you have a single type called `Component`, you can think of it as a single type with three constructors: `Position`, `Velocity` and `Appearance`.  You can also deconstruct the type again using the same three cases by pattern matching.

e.g.

```
match comp with
|Position -> ..
|Velocity -> ..
|Appearance -> ..
```

---

Hopefully, it should now come as no surprise that the type abbreviation  `Position` that you declared has no connection with the union case `Position` that you declared as part of the `Component` type.  They are entirely independent of one another.

`Position` means `Vector2` and `Component` is a completely seperate union type.

Assuming you wanted a `Component` type that could contain multiple things, you would need to associate some values with the cases.  Here is an example of creating such a Discriminated Union:

```
type Component = 
    | Position of Vector2
    | Velocity of Vector2
    | Appearance of string
```

---

Now, let's look at the next problem.

If we delete the type abbreviations and try the rest of the code with our new Discriminated Union

```
let components = List<Dictionary<string, Component>>()
let pos = Dictionary<string, Position>()
```

We now have a new error:

> The type `Position` is not defined.

Well, remember what I said earlier about `Component`.  `Component` is the type, `Position` is not a type, it's a union case of `Component`.

If you wanted to contain entire dictionaries of the same one of these options, you might be better changing your definition to something like this:

```
type ComponentDictionary =
    |PositionDictionary of Dictionary<string, Vector2>
    |VelocityDictionary of Dictionary<string, Vector2>
    |AppearanceDictionary of Dictionary<string, string>
```

Then you could create a `ResizeArray`/`List` of these.

```
let components = ResizeArray<ComponentDictionary>()
```

Now, in order to populated this collection, we then just need use the appropriate case constructor for `ComponentDictionary`

```
let pos = PositionDictionary (Dictionary<string, Vector2>())
```

Now, pos is of type `ComponentDictionary` so we can add it to components:

```
components.Add(pos) // No error here!
```

Answer (score 0):

TheInnerLight's answer is very complete. I would like to add that there might be some advantage of using pure F# types (list, map or dict) instead of the generic .Net List and Dictionary. Of course you might actually need the .NET generic collections. Here is a simple example which uses map (or dict) and creates a list of various Component maps:

```
type Vector2 = float * float

type Component = 
    | Position of Vector2
    | Velocity of Vector2 
    | Appearance of string

type Components = list<Map<string,Component>> // this is not strictly necessary

let pos = Position(10.,20.)
let app = Appearance "here"

let compMap1= Map.empty<string,Component> // define an empty map for Component
let compMap1 = compMap1.Add("key1",pos).Add("key2",app) // or: let compMap1' = dict(["key1",pos;"key2",app])
let compMap2 = ["key3",pos;"key4",pos] |> Map.ofList // you can create map from a list
let (components:Components) = [compMap1;compMap2] // make a list of your maps
let components' = [compMap1;compMap2] // or just use a generic F# list
(*
val components' : Map<string,Component> list =
  [map [("key1", Position (10.0, 20.0)); ("key2", Appearance "here")];
   map [("key3", Position (10.0, 20.0)); ("key4", Position (10.0, 20.0))]]
*)
```

And if would just need a list (or Array, or whatever) that  holds various component types you can already do it:

```
let compList = [pos;app]
//val compList : Component list = [Position (10.0, 20.0); Appearance "here"]
```